# How do I programmatically maximize a top-level window in a Win32 C++ program?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to programmatically maximize my top-level window in my Win32 C++ program.  I'm using code similar to the following in the code that handles the `WM_CREATE` message:

```
        WINDOWPLACEMENT windowPlacement = {};
        windowPlacement.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
        windowPlacement.rcNormalPosition = newWindowRect;
        windowPlacement.showCmd = SW_NORMAL;

        if (maximized == TRUE)
        {
            windowPlacement.showCmd = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;
        }
        SetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &windowPlacement);
```

When this code executes, if `maximized` is `TRUE`, the window is set to the size of a maximized window, but the maximize/restore button is still a maximize button, not a restore button.

[image: screenshot of window]

I've tried using the `ShowWindow()` function with the same results.

Comment: What happens if you click ont the maximue/restore button?

Comment: I think you want [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles he has tried with `ShowWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the `WM_CREATE` message handler was the wrong place to do this.  After moving the code out of the window procedure and into the `wWinMain()` function after the call to `CreateWindow()` but before the call to `ShowWindow()`, it works as expected.